# how to update and delete two tables together

Tags: sql, database

i am unable to update and delete two tables together i have a purchase and stock table. On updating purchase stock should be updated with it and on deleting the purchase data the stock should also be deleted.

Comment: I'd probably use triggers! (Or views.)

Comment: please help out with an example code for it

Comment: Adding more words to your question would be a good start :)

Comment: You have to do the work. If you want someone to do it for you, hire that person!

Comment: For the dual updating part, you might need a trigger.  For the deletion part, on delete cascade might be possible.

Comment: thanks for the idea

Comment: Using triggers can make the code more complex and hard to read. It is better to execute these batch sql's in a transaction.

Comment: Or in a stored procedure, so you can see the complete code that makes all the edits, and you can do it in a transaction so it can be fully rolled back if needed

Comment: @Burc, and end up with data inconsistency when someone takes another way doing the updates/inserts.

Comment: @jarlh, different perspectives brings different ideas.. For my opinion, if "someone" can update/insert data without knowledge, there's a big problem here but as I said, this may change according to conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an UPDATE trigger which deletes the content of two tables as per your need whenever you update them. Below SQL does it for Purchase table. You can extend the same by joining Stock table as well.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Purchase_UPDATE]
       ON [dbo].[Purchase]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       DELETE FROM Purchase WHERE [Your condition]
END
```